# MVC routing with duplicate method entry points

Tags: c#, url-routing

The 3 methods below all need to have the same name: "Roles"

They need to be the same as I have a permissions system that will only allow the execution of a "Roles" method.

I don't feel too happy about the third method because in order to keep the compiler happy, I have to declare a pointless and never used string variable.

Can anyone think of a better way of doing this?

```
public partial class PartialsController
{
    [Route("roles")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Roles()
    {
        ViewBag.InitialData = await Uow.Roles.Query(InitialQuery("name", "asc"));
        return PartialView("Roles/ListRoles");
    }

    [Route("roles/{id:guid}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Roles(Guid id)
    {
        ViewBag.Role = await Uow.Roles.GetById(id);
        ViewBag.Permissions = await Uow.Permissions.GetAll().Select(p => new { p.Id, p.Description }).ToListAsync();
        return PartialView("Roles/EditRole");
    }

    [Route("roles/new")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Roles(string nothing)
    {
        ViewBag.Permissions = await Uow.Permissions.GetAll().Select(p => new { p.Id, p.Description }).ToListAsync();
        return PartialView("Roles/EditRole");
    }
}
```